# No email notices on comments etc.

Tags: support, email, notifications

Hei, shouldn't i be notified by email if someone starts a comment with @wyrfel ? I don't get any email notifications at all, even though correct email address is in profile (it was pulled form my OpenID). Could this be a privacy setting in my OpenID? Or did i do something else wrong?

Answer (score 2):

You only get (semi-)daily mails for new answers to your questions. This is by design, because [the intention is that you check the site regularly](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14555/notify-more-frequently-than-once-a-day/14600#14600) (and answer other questions), not that you wait until you get a mail.

I somewhat agree with that, except for new users that post one question and checked the "notify me of new answers" box: they will never know that someone asked for clarification in a comment. You can [support my proposal to send them mails for comments too](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76709/daily-mail-notification-should-include-comments-on-questions).